# git deleted a branch, but changes still staged on master

Tags: git

I was working on a branch in my git repo and just messed it up and wanted to just get rid of the changes.

So, I didn't commit the changes and checked out my master branch and then did `git branch -D "branch_to_remove"`.

However, the files are still in my directory and the changes are still staged for commit on my master branch.

How can i get rid of all those changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset your working directory to the master with:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD
```

To delete the untracked files, I usually use (modified following @Mark Longair's comments):

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard --others --directory -z | xargs -0 rm -i
```

**Edit**

Or use `git clean -d` as Noufal suggested in the comments in another answer (now deleted).

Comment: great, thanks I ended up using git clean -f -d and that worked out!

Comment: A few comments: (a) you don't need to use `-I` in xargs if you're just putting the arguments at the end of the command line (b) parsing the output of `git status` to find untracked files is less robust than using `git ls-files --exclude-standard --others --directory` (c) also, you could add `-z` to that command and `-0` to your `xargs` invocation to also cope with filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: Hey thanks! Shell snippets are fun, but there's much to get wrong. I guess using `git clean` is the safer choice in the end.

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Although, frankly, I've accidentally lost data using all of these commands except for `git checkout master` :)